# How can I apply distinct on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, distinct

Hi friends I have table from customer where in I want to get distinct values of its three columns CustomerType, CustomerReg,CustomerID.

Instead of doing three separate queries for the distinct

like select distinct CustomerType From Customer.. and then for CustomerReg..Can it be achieved in one query...

The reason is that i would attach each column distinct values to a specific drop down list box..

Comment: Great! what have you tried and where are you getting stuck? Please review [ask] for tips on how to formulate a great questions and get help faster..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `grouping sets`.  If you want the values in three separate columns:

```
select CustomerType, CustomerReg, CustomerId
from Customer
group by grouping sets ((CustomerType), (CustomerReg), (CustomerId))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to show a distinct list of all the customer types, customerreg and customerIds in a list, in one column?

Try this...

```
select distinct CustomerType + ' : ' + CustomerReg + ' (' + CustomerId + ')' as Name
from Customer
```

This will return a string like 'External : 23423412 (2344)'
You should probably order it by something meaningful too.
Try adding

```
order by Name
```

Although, you shouldn't need the DISTINCT if a customer can only appear once in the customer table.

Reading your question again, it looks like you want to return a distinct list of each column in one query, not a distinct combination? Then the group by grouping sets mentioned above will probably get you the closest, although depending on the structure of your data, performance might become an issue here if you have lots of customers.

What language are you using in your UI? 
If it's .Net, you could open a datareader using 3 separate queries, and then use the datareader.nextresult

There's an explanation here,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.data.framework.datareader.nextresult.aspx

and an example here,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can even do it like this:

```
select distinct CustomerType, CustomerReg, CustomerId
from Customer
```